# How to remove Polaris Office on HTC phones?

Tags: uninstallation, htc-sense, polaris-office

I have Polaris Office installed on my HTC Sense 6, but I cannot delete or find it on my installed apps, Play Store, and even Device Administrators. Though, I can run the app and use it.

How am I going to delete it?

Comment: what app is it? Sometimes they're named strangely in the app list.

Comment: OP: Please clarify: What application? From where are you able to open it?

Comment: It's Polaris office. Not listed on playstore, cannot discover it VIA file managers, not a device admin and uninstall option is grayed out.

Comment: let me suggest something. let someone transfer the latest updated version of the app as apk file(via any app sharer) then install it on your phone that will upgrade your app and possibly fix the problem

Comment: Could you clarify your phone model? AFAIK, Sense 6 is not the phone model, but the version of HTC UI framework.

Comment: @Andrew yes its the framework.

Comment: @Devrim if your rooted it would be simple, you can use a system app remover such as [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jumobile.manager.systemapp&hl=en).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [HTC Rezound (Verizon Wireless)'s FAQ](http://www.htc.com/us/support/htc-rezound-verizon-wireless/faq/4/) (I know it's a different device, but it's same for most HTC phones),

> ## What is Polaris Office?
>
> Polaris Office comes **pre-loaded on the phone** and can be used to open and view office documents (Word, Excel, PowerPoint) received in email as attachments or stored on the SD Card. [...]

<sub>(Emphasis mine)</sub>

In other words, it's a [bloatware](http://www.andromods.com/tips-trick/how-to-remove-bloatware-verizon-htc-one-m8-safe-list.html). You need to have root access to uninstall bloatware.

If not, you can still disable it. Since it's not installed as a normal application, it won't be listed as your installed apps. Instead, you have to select "All" tab to list all apps, including bloatware. Then you can find and disable the app from there.

Alternatively, long-press the app from the app drawer (not home screen). There should be "App Info" on the top of the screen. Drag to there and release, and it should open the app info where you can disable it.

Comment: Thanks @andew I realised it is actually a bloatware after checking another device yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

If you can run the app and use it this means there is a widget where you can use to enter.

Long press that widget(app icon) from home screen, since long pressing from app drawer just adds it to home screen, choose app info, this will redirect you to the app in the application manager where you will have options to uninstall or clear data...

Comment: Long pressing on sense ads a shortcut on the homepage.

Comment: long pressing from almost every android adds on homepage... i ment from the homepage

Comment: Not every app has a widget associated with it. Polaris doesn't have a widget. A shortcut isn't the same thing.